# How to control page layout using minipage(s)

Tags: graphics, minipage, layout

I'm trying to control the layout of a page by using minipages, but I can't
seem to get it working nicely so feel i must be doing something wrong.

This is what I currently have :

[image]

The code for which is here :

```
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c][.5\textwidth]{.9\textwidth}
\fbox{%for testing only
\begin{minipage}[c][.45\textwidth]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{%for testing only
\begin{minipage}[c][.45\textwidth]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{minipage}
}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c][.5\textwidth]{.9\textwidth}
\fbox{%for testing only
\begin{minipage}[c][.45\textwidth]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{%for testing only
\begin{minipage}[c][.45\textwidth]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{minipage}
}
```

What I would have expected to happen is for the images to change dynamically
within the nested minipages. By which I mean - if i set `0.5\textwidth` when
there's a minipage set to `0.5\textwidth` then the box would actually be
given `0.5*0.5=0.25\textwidth`.

if i change the first mini-page call to
`\begin{minipage}[c][.2\textwidth]{.9\textwidth}` then I get the following :

[image]

This is an issue because i will likely be having a different section heading
font size, and possibly footer, so I need to be able to adjust these
sections.

Comment: I changed the links to embedded images. Hope that's fine with you.

Comment: @leandriis yes sorry, i meant to do so. Thank you

Comment: Like \makebox and \raisebox, minipage can cram more into a given size than will fit, causing it to overlay the top and bottom.  Note that the third optional argument (default [c]) handles the placement of boxes inside the minipage.  You probably want the [s] option.

Comment: Not sure of youl goal, but the output is the expected for that code. `.9\linewidth` is the 90% of the width of the minipage where the image is, so the 90% of  `.45/textwidth`, that is 45% of the width of the container minipage, that is the 90% of the text width of the page, so your image is near 1/3 (36%) of the text width (0.9*0.45*0.9=0.36) *of the page*. Note  that `linewidth` and `textwidth` is not always the same length. Be sure of understand the difference to avoid unexpected results.